# Error when compiling QXmpp library on Qt 5.4

Tags: c++, qt, xmpp, qxmpp

I try since this morning to compile a XMPP library for QT calles qxmpp.

I try to use Qt Creator and do a Build All, but the compiler can't find a thing called -lqxmpp0 and I don't know what it is. Google wasn't helpful unfortunately.

My Qt window:
[image]

[github Library](https://github.com/qxmpp-project/qxmpp)

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: @cmannett85 here : https://github.com/qxmpp-project/qxmpp/blob/master/qxmpp.pri

Comment: It looks like it's trying to build the examples before the library, or the library had been built but it's in a place g++ can't find.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if in the qxmpp.pri have something like this define:

```
QXMPP_INCLUDEPATH = $$PWD/src/base $$PWD/src/client $$PWD/src/server

# Determine library name
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    QXMPP_LIBRARY_NAME = qxmpp_d
} else {
    QXMPP_LIBRARY_NAME = qxmpp
}

# Determine library type (shared or staticlib)
isEmpty(QXMPP_LIBRARY_TYPE) {
    android | ios {
        QXMPP_LIBRARY_TYPE = staticlib
    } else {
        QXMPP_LIBRARY_TYPE = shared
    }
}
```

has you see the QXMPP_LIBRARY_NAME defines the name of the library, also check if in the examples.pro is included qxmpp.pri. I hope my answer can help.

Comment: also check if in the qxmpp.pro add subdirs examples before src

Answer (score -1):

> -llibrary
> -l library
>
> Search the library named library when linking. (The second alternative with the library as a separate argument is only for POSIX
> compliance and is not recommended.)
>
> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the
> order they are specified. Thus, ‘foo.o -lz bar.o’ searches library ‘z’
> after file foo.o but before bar.o. If bar.o refers to functions in
> ‘z’, those functions may not be loaded.
>
> **The linker searches a standard list of directories for the library,
> which is actually a file named liblibrary.a.** The linker then
> uses this file as if it had been specified precisely by name.
>
> **The directories searched include several standard system directories plus any that you specify with -L.**
>
> Normally the files found this way are library files—archive files whose members are object files. The linker handles an archive file by
> scanning through it for members which define symbols that have so far
> been referenced but not defined. But if the file that is found is an
> ordinary object file, it is linked in the usual fashion. The only
> difference between using an -l option and specifying a file name is
> that -l surrounds library with ‘lib’ and ‘.a’ and searches several
> directories.

---

### https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

Comment: Thanks for replying. I will be honest with you, I don't really understand what you mean. Do I have to change something in Qt ?